# Setting width (pixel) of spreadsheet cell using PhpSpreadsheet

Tags: phpspreadsheet

- when export file excel and open, i have a problem:
  The excel file's column expands with each screen size and I want to fix its width for all screens.
- Note: I want to set width in pixcel units.
- This is my code:

```
  $this->_

    phpExcel->getActiveSheet()->getColumnDimension('A')->setAutoSize(false);
            $this->_phpExcel->getActiveSheet()->getColumnDimension('A')->setWidth(35.73);
            $this->_phpExcel->getActiveSheet()->getColumnDimension('B')->setAutoSize(false);
            $this->_phpExcel->getActiveSheet()->getColumnDimension('B')->setWidth(35.73);
            $this->_phpExcel->getActiveSheet()->getColumnDimension('C')->setAutoSize(false);
            $this->_phpExcel->getActiveSheet()->getColumnDimension('C')->setWidth(10.72);
            $this->_phpExcel->getActiveSheet()->getColumnDimension('D')->setAutoSize(false);
            $this->_phpExcel->getActiveSheet()->getColumnDimension('D')->setWidth(11.53);
            $this->_phpExcel->getActiveSheet()->getColumnDimension('E')->setAutoSize(false);
            $this->_phpExcel->getActiveSheet()->getColumnDimension('E')->setWidth(17.44);
```

Comment: If the excel default font is different on another computer the sizes will be different because excel calculates the size based of the size of a single character in the default font. Make sure all default fonts are the same in each excel and it should work.

Comment: I have set the default font and this is a common font on excel. But with cell expands with each screen size

Comment: I don't think you'll be able to change how Excel operates when something is opened on screens with different sizes. Nor can you change how someone might adjust the width of columns based on their own preferences.